# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined when render React app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, webpack-5

In a React project ("react": "^17.0.2", Node: v17.4.0) I getting  message like this.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EPXY4.png

Using "webpack": "^5.69.0"

There are no error in the console.
I haven’t webpack.config file.

What the problem can be?
I'll be happy to share more information if you need, TNX

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.